# Android - notifyDataSetChanged() and threads

Tags: android-asynctask, android, android-adapter

I have an AsyncTask that does some number crunching (more details in the next few lines) in the `doInBackground()` method. The data manipulated in `doInBackground()` is the data associated with a `ListView's` adapter ( a `SimpleAdapter` in my case). What I need to do after I process the adapter's data is call `notifyDataSetChanged()` and update my `ListView`. But calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` within `doInBackground()` displays the "Unfortunately 'app name' has stopped working" message. My error stack shows this:

> 06-22 08:01:49.083: E/AndroidRuntime(9955): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
>   06-22 08:01:49.083: E/AndroidRuntime(9955): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>   06-22 08:01:49.083: E/AndroidRuntime(9955):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
>   06-22 08:01:49.083: E/AndroidRuntime(9955):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
>   06-22 08:01:49.083: E/AndroidRuntime(9955):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
>   06-22 08:01:49.083: E/AndroidRuntime(9955):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
>   06-22 08:01:49.083: E/AndroidRuntime(9955):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
>   06-22 08:01:49.083: E/AndroidRuntime(9955):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
>   06-22 08:01:49.083: E/AndroidRuntime(9955):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
>   06-22 08:01:49.083: E/AndroidRuntime(9955):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)
>   06-22 08:01:49.083: E/AndroidRuntime(9955): Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

The last line

> 06-22 08:01:49.083: E/AndroidRuntime(9955): Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

gives me the information I need to debug. I solved this problem by calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` from `onPostExecute()` But what I still don't understand is how the method actually works. My questions are:

Q1. How does `notifyDataSetChanged()` actually update the UI ?

Q2. What is the connection between `notifyDataSetChanged()` and the UI thread ?

Q3. Is there any method in which `notifyDataSetChanged()` can be called on a worker thread ?

I am a beginner with Android and any help with these fundamental questions would be most appreciated. My internet searches have not given me the answers I wanted. Also thank you very much for your time.

Comment: better override onProgressUpdate in Async Task and call publishProgress() from doInBackground to update the UI.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Q1. How does notifyDataSetChanged() actually update the UI ?

Actually, `notifyDataSetChanged()` only fires the `onChanged()` method on its associated observers. For `AdapterView` subclasses (such as `ListView`), this ends up calling `requestLayout()`, which [**schedules** a layout pass of the view tree](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestLayout%28%29).

This means that the `ListView` does not "immediately" recreate its children views, but it will do so as soon as the UI thread is free to process messages. Eventually, `getView()` will be called for each item.

> Q2. What is the connection between notifyDataSetChanged() and the UI
>   thread ?

Basically, modifying an Adapter's contents from a background thread is not allowed. `notifyDataSetChanged()` is just the way to notify the `AdapterView` that its data has changed, and it should be redrawn.

> Q3. Is there any method in which notifyDataSetChanged() can be called
>   on a worker thread ?

Actually, there are several. You can use a [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html), [`AsyncTask.onPostExecute()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29), [`Activity.runOnUiThread()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) or [`View.post()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#post%28java.lang.Runnable%29).

Comment: I don't understand your answer to Question 3. He clearly asked for a method which can be invoked on worker thread and in which notifyDataSetChanged() can be called. You have given answers of method which run on UI thread.

Comment: @Raymond232 I understood "a method" as "a way to" :)

Comment: Thank you so much! `view?.post { adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() }` did the trick for me. Could not wrap my head around this nasty bug in my app after upgrading google play billing, which now queries SKUs threaded.

Answer (score 3):

```
How does notifyDataSetChanged() actually update the UI ?
```

It changes your ListView items that was added previously thus actually changes your UI.

**example**: when you `add/remove` to the `array` that was passed to the **adapter**.

```
What is the connection between notifyDataSetChanged() and the UI thread ?
```

When you create a view from the UI thread it is the only thread that can update/change your view nothing else and if you are trying to update it from different thread youll get this error: `CalledFromWrongThreadException`.

```
 Is there any method in which notifyDataSetChanged() can be called on a worker thread ?
```

Yes there is, you can call the activity's `runOnUiThread` to call the main/UI thread to enable you to update your ListView.

**sample:**

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
             //notifyDataSetChanged here or update your UI on different thread
        }
    });
```